# Max HEX value for long type

Tags: c#, java, types, long-integer

I have ported Java code to C#.
Could you please explain why I have compile-time error in the follow line (I use VS 2008):

```
    private long l = 0xffffffffffffffffL; // 16 'f' got here
```

*Cannot convert source type ulong to target type long*

I need the same value here as for origin Java code.

Comment: Don't you get an error in Java when you do that? In any case, the result would be -1, wouldn't it? Java's long type is signed too.

Comment: It's all OK with Java in this case. Yes in Java the result is "-1" but if the same is true for C# - why my value can't be assigned?

Comment: In that case, the wording in your question isn't correct. Everyone assumed that you wanted the maximum value for a long. And -1 isn't it. On the other hand, if you wanted -1, why not just write -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you aren't worried about negative values, you could try using an [`unsigned long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
private ulong l = 0xffffffffffffffffL;
```

In Java the actual value of `l` would be `-1`, because it would overflow the `2^63 - 1` maximum value, so you could just replace your constant with `-1`.

Comment: Hm... but for Java my value means "-1" but here - not. Don't?

Comment: Yes, because C# cares about overflowed values. Java isn't so stringent and allows it.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't mind if a constant overflows in this particular situation - the value you've given is actually -1.

The simplest way of achieving the same effect in C# is:

```
private long l = -1;
```

If you want to retain the 16 fs you could use:

```
private long l = unchecked((long) 0xffffffffffffffffUL);
```

If you *actually* want the maximum value for a signed long, you should use:

```
// Java
private long l = Long.MAX_VALUE;
// C#
private long l = long.MaxValue;
```

Comment: But why "-1" represented in Hex can not be assigned to 64-bit signed long?

Comment: You're not listening. 0xffffffffffffffff isn't -1 in hex, it's 18,446,744,073,709,551,615  in hex.

Comment: @MichaelZ: 0xfff... is only -1 when it overflows the boundaries of a signed long. You can use -0x1, which is *really* -1 in hex.

Answer (score 2):

`0xffffffffffffffff` is larger than a signed long can represent.

You can insert a cast:

```
 private long l = unchecked( (long)0xffffffffffffffffL);
```

Since C# uses two's complement, `0xffffffffffffffff` represents `-1`:

```
private long l = -1;
```

Or declare the variable as unsigned, which is probably the cleanest choice if you want to represent bit patterns:

```
private ulong l = 0xffffffffffffffffL;
private ulong l = ulong.MaxValue;
```

The maximal value of a singed long is:

```
private long l = 0x7fffffffffffffffL;
```

But that's better written as `long.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
private long l = long.MaxValue;
```

... but as mdm pointed out, you probably actually want a ulong.

```
private ulong l = ulong.MaxValue;
```