# Error in converting String column to binary column

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a `udf` that will convert a hexadecimal string (with hyphens in it that need to be removed) into binary type.  Here is what I have:

```
  val df3 = 
    finalDf2.withColumn("vesselId2", vesselIdToByteArrayUdf(finalDf2.col("vesselId")))

  private val vesselIdToByteArray = (vesselId: String) => {
    val newString: String = vesselId.replaceAll("\\-","")
    val number: Long = Long2long(java.lang.Long.valueOf(newString, 16))

    BigInt(number).toByteArray
  }

  private val vesselIdToByteArrayUdf = udf(vesselIdToByteArray)
```

This isn't working.  Note that I'm not claiming that the intermediate step of converting the String to a Long is correct.  In fact, I know for a fact that it isn't.  I simply want to convert the String column to a binary column by whatever way works.

=================================

I guess I can't answer this because it's supposedly a duplicate.  Anyway, here is the solution I found:

```
  private val vesselIdToByteArray = (vesselId: String) => {
    val newString: String = vesselId.replaceAll("\\-","")
    val number: BigInt = math.BigInt(newString, 16)

    number.toByteArray
  }
```

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825469/2707792) mentions what the MaxValue of a signed `Long` is.

Comment: *"it's supposedly a duplicate"* - it was a duplicate, at least before you edited out the actual error message with the `NumberFormatException`. Even if it wasn't a duplicate, if you took a few minutes to delete all the apache-spark related noise, and actually produce a [mcve], then the question would reduce to *"How do I construct a `BigInt` from a `String` with a hexadecimal number"*, to which the obvious answer would be *"Use [`BigInt.apply(x: String, radix: Int)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/math/BigInt$.html#apply(x:String,radix:Int):scala.math.BigInt) constructor"*.

Comment: If you want to try it with an MCVE, I would suggest that you ask a new question about how to construct `BigInt`s from hexadecimal `String`s. With a good, searchable title and appropriate tags, it would have *some* chance of becoming a canonical duplicate target (unless it gets downvoted because it *"does not show any research effort"* - it's literally just invoking the second method listed [in the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/math/BigInt$.html#apply(x:String,radix:Int):scala.math.BigInt)).